# How can I have .flowconfig read types from a folder?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a folder called `interfaces`:

[image]

In `finale.js`, I have:

```
// @flow 
type finaleContext = {
    instance: string
}

export type { finaleContext }
```

I want this to be picked up by flow. In `.flowconfig`, I tried:

```
[libs]
./interfaces/*.js
```

And it still complains: `Cannot resolve name finaleContext.`

So how can I include all of these interfaces as definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each line in the `[libs]` section is a path to the library file or directory which you would like to include. These paths can be relative to the project root directory or absolute. Including a directory recursively includes all the files under that directory as library files.

https://flow.org/en/docs/config/libs/

So, I think you can just write

```
[libs]
interfaces
```